# Conceptual Assistance with Python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

So I'm given a problem that I must find the solution to. I got the question wrong but I want to know why the correct answer is right. Can anyone explain the solution to the following code for me please?

```
dog='Zoomie'
pattern=''
for letter in dog:
    inPattern=False
    if dog.count(letter)>1:
        pattern+=letter
        inPattern=True
    if dog.count(letter)>0 and inPattern==False:
        pattern+=letter
    else:
        pattern+='.'
```

The output is: Zo.o.mie

Granted it's a very simple and basic Python problem, but it's still kind of confusing for me.

Comment: what is wrong and what is write? what is the given problem? what output do you expect to have?

Comment: what do you need to know? why it outputs Zo.o.mie ? because it does so...try to analyze your code, take each of your word's letter and pass it through the if's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is adding dots for any letter that has one or more occurrence in the *entire* string.

- On the first pass, `Z` has no letter count greater than 1.  `inPattern` isn't set, so we simply append to `pattern`.
- On the second pass, we have more than one occurrence of `o`, so we append the letter to the pattern and set our flag `inPattern` to be `True`.  Since `inPattern` isn't `False`, we fall through to append a `.` into `pattern`.

The rest reads very similar to this.

Look at other words, such as "racecar" or "aplanamanacanalpanama" (both obvious palindromes), to see what you'd wind up with.  (I'd expect dots between [almost] every letter, honestly.)

Comment: But how does the computer know that the program has more than one occurrence of o when the for loop has to go through every letter? Doesn't it have to go through every letter in the for loop, so for example, when it goes through Z, it adds it to the string because it's only 1 occurrence, but when it encounters o, isn't it encountering o for the first time? Therefore doesn't o at that point have only 1 occurrence? What I expected it to be was Zoo.mie.

Comment: The [string method `count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) is providing that information.

Comment: so just making sure, the computer goes through each if statement right? I keep thinking it processes the same way as an elif statement.

Comment: For this case, Python will interpret both `if` statements independently, since there's not an `elif` between the two.  An `if-elif-else` will only fire if one of those conditions are true (or `else`; two chained `if` statements will always fire to check their conditions (at the bare minimum).